# Add collinear points to polyshape (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, polygon

I want to do something everyone else normally avoids:
I've got two polygons (polyshape objects), `layer1` and `layer2`. `layer1` is to be extended by the intersection points of the two polygons. By definition, these points are collinear with the edges of `layer1`. I want this to work for any polygon shape.

**Example:**

Assume this definition for the two polygons:

```
square = polyshape([0,0;0,6;6,6;6,0]);
layer1 = addboundary(square, [1,2,5,4], [1,1,5,5]);
layer2 = addboundary(square, [4,5,2,1], [1,1,5,5]);
```

Expected result after adding the extension:

```
>> layer1.Vertices

ans =

         0         0
         0    6.0000
    6.0000    6.0000
    6.0000         0
       NaN       NaN
    1.0000    1.0000
    2.0000    1.0000
    3.0000    2.3333
    3.5000    3.0000
    5.0000    5.0000
    4.0000    5.0000
    3.0000    3.6667
    2.5000    3.0000
```

**Solution approaches:**

Matlab provides two promising tools: Each boolean function (intersect, union, xor, subtract) can be instructed to keep collinear points. And each boolean function also returns `shapeID` and `vertexID`, telling you where each point comes from.

- At first, I thought it would be enough to add all points with `shapeID == 0`. But I don't know how to put these additional points in the right order with the points already existing.
- So I tried some stuff combining the boolean functions.
  `layer1 = union(layer1, subtract(layer1, layer2), 'KeepCollinearPoints', true);`
  doesn't catch all intersections (for a reason I don't understand - it works for `layer2 = union(layer2, subtract(layer2, layer1), 'KeepCollinearPoints', true);`).
- Something like

  ```
  [layer1,shapeID,~] = intersect(layer1,layer2);
  layer1 = polyshape(layer1.Vertices(shapeID~=2,:), 'KeepCollinearPoints', true);
  ```

  seem to work, but not for all polygon shapes (e.g. `layer1 = addboundary(square, [1,5,2.5], [2,2,4]);` has not the desired result)

I feel there must be an elegant solution to my problem that I just have not found yet. I appreciate any help.